# using std::is_same, why my function still can't work for 2 types

Tags: c++, templates, types

I am trying to write a function that can print both stack and queue, my code is as following

```
template<typename Cont>
void print_container(Cont& cont){
    while(!cont.empty()){
        if(std::is_same<Cont, stack<int>>::value){
            auto elem = cont.top();
            std::cout << elem << '\n';
        } else {
            auto elem = cont.front();
            std::cout << elem << '\n';
        }
        cont.pop();
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stack<int> stk;
    stk.push(1);
    stk.push(2);
    stk.push(3);
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);

    std::cout << "print stack" << endl;
    print_container(stk);
    std::cout << "print queue" << endl;
    print_container(q);

    return 0;
}
```

**But it doesn't work here**, the error info is:

```
demo_typeof.cpp:35:30: error: no member named 'front' in 'std::__1::stack<int, std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >'
            auto elem = cont.front();
                        ~~~~ ^
demo_typeof.cpp:52:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'print_container<std::__1::stack<int, std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
    print_container(stk);
    ^
demo_typeof.cpp:32:30: error: no member named 'top' in 'std::__1::queue<int, std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >'
            auto elem = cont.top();
                        ~~~~ ^
demo_typeof.cpp:54:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'print_container<std::__1::queue<int, std::__1::deque<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
    print_container(q);
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

I know it's problematic, and know C++ is statically typed and without too much Runtime support. but I am wondering the specific reason why this doesn't work, and how to deal with it.

P.S.: The actual meaning of judge the typing of a container is that: You can simply change a DFS function into BFS by passing a queue container instead of a stack. So, BFS and DFS can share most of the code.

P.P.S: I am in C++ 11 environment, but answers for older or later standard are also welcomed.

Comment: As it stands, the compiler tries to compile both branches of the `if` statement no matter the type, and it always fails for one of them.

Comment: Because both branches of `if`-`else` statement must be compilable, which are not in your case. You can use `if constexpr` from C++17, or some solution based on SFINAE, partial specializtion, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both branches of `if`-`else` statement must be compilable, which are not in your case. One of many possible solutions that is based on partial specialization and should work even in C++98:

```
template <typename Cont>
struct element_accessor;

template <typename T>
struct element_accessor<std::stack<T>> {
   const T& operator()(const std::stack<T>& s) const { return s.top(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct element_accessor<std::queue<T>> {
   const T& operator()(const std::queue<T>& q) const { return q.front(); }
};

template<typename Cont>
void print_container(Cont& cont){
   while(!cont.empty()){
      auto elem = element_accessor<Cont>{}(cont);
      std::cout << elem << '\n';
      cont.pop();
   }
}
```

---

A C++17 solution with `if constexpr`:

```
template<template<class> typename Cont, typename T>
void print_container(Cont<T>& cont){
   while(!cont.empty()){
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Cont<T>, std::stack<T>>) 
         std::cout << cont.top() << '\n';
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Cont<T>, std::queue<T>>) 
         std::cout << cont.front() << '\n';
      cont.pop();
   }
}
```

Comment: oh this is C++ elegant :thumbs_up:

Comment: You don't need structs nor partial specialization, you can just make an overloaded function: `template <typename T> auto &element_accessor(const std::stack<T> &s) {return s.top();}`, and similarly for `queue`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure, but this solution has already appeared in other answer. And OP, for some reason, likes specialization more.

Comment: @YanTing_ThePanda Is there a reason you consider this more elegant than your solution?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, I am looking for a solution using SFINAE but don't know how to write it, that's the reason why I accept this answer.   In addition, I personally think `element_accessor ` is a more general abstraction, which can work at more places.

Comment: @YanTing_ThePanda At least in my opinion your solution is better. It essentially does the same thing as this solution, but with less code. Also, I don't see any reason to use SFINAE in this case, but should you ever need it, it would easier to use it with function overloads than with class template specializations.

Answer (score 9):

I answered my own question by simply using overloads.

```
template<typename Elem>
Elem get_first_elem(stack<Elem>& cont){
    return cont.top();
}
template<typename Elem>
Elem get_first_elem(queue<Elem>& cont){
    return cont.front();
}

template<typename Cont>
void print_container(Cont& cont){
    while(!cont.empty()){
        auto elem = get_first_elem(cont);
        cont.pop();
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on what is your definition of _"better way"_ :)

Comment: @DanielLangr it's like being more canonical and general, instead of just a dirty hack :-)

Comment: In my view this is the best way. ADL allows us to express intent in a uniform way (as you have done) even when the details of how that intent is realised differ for different containers/data types.

Comment: @RichardHodges Agree. For generic solution, I would just return by (`const`) reference, since this is what `stack<T>::top` and `queue<T>::front` do. Or, better use `decltype(auto)` as return type if C++14 is available.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with

```
if(std::is_same<Cont, stack<int>>::value)
    ...
else
    +++
```

Is that if `...` or `+++` would not compile then you can't use it.  Even though you can only take one branch or the other both branches get compiled and if the syntax isn't valid then you get a compiler error.  With C++17's [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) though the behavior is different.  The condition will be resolved at compile time and only the branch that is taken will actually be compiled.  The rest of the code is discarded.  Switching to that you code would look like

```
template<typename Cont>
void print_container(Cont& cont){
    while(!cont.empty()){
        if constexpr(std::is_same<Cont, stack<int>>::value){
            auto elem = cont.top();
            std::cout << elem << '\n';
        } else {
            auto elem = cont.front();
            std::cout << elem << '\n';
        }
        cont.pop();
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++17 then what you want is [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

```
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename Cont>
void print_container(Cont& cont){
    while(!cont.empty()){
        if constexpr(std::is_same<Cont, stack<int>>::value){
            auto elem = cont.top();
            std::cout << elem << '\n';
        } else {
            auto elem = cont.front();
            std::cout << elem << '\n';
        }
        cont.pop();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stack<int> stk;
    stk.push(1);
    stk.push(2);
    stk.push(3);
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(1);
    q.push(2);
    q.push(3);

    std::cout << "print stack" << endl;
    print_container(stk);
    std::cout << "print queue" << endl;
    print_container(q);

    return 0;
}
```