# Conditional code compilation with C++ templates

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, compile-time

I have a template class and I would like to conditionally compile code depending on a `static constexpr bool` member of the template parameter `T`:

```
template <typename T>
class A : public T {
  explicit A() {
     ...
     if(T::boolmember) {
        T::intmember1++;
     } else {
        T::intmember2++
     }
  }
}
```

This will not compile: only types `T` which have member `boolmember` as `true` contain a member variable `intmember1`; only types `T` which have `boolmember` as `false` contain a member variable `intmember2`.

How could I do this? Of course one option is to write template specializations for each function where this situation occurs. There are two issues with this approach:

- Variable `T::boolmember` is not one of the parameters of the class template.
- This situation occurs very often throughout my code, always in small pieces of code, and with different conditions. Doing so would defeat the purpose of template metaprogramming.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Just answered a very related question earlier toda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253286/using-stdis-same-why-my-function-still-cant-work-for-2-types

Comment: Didn't know about "if constexpr", thanks! (Also, it's surprising this wasn't in the standard until C++17...)