# Why does the string version of this template function compile but the float version doesn't?

Tags: c++, templates

I don't have much experience with templating in C++, but I know it can be very handy and am trying to use it more.

I created the following example code which does not compile, with the compiler complaining about potentially assigning a `string` to a `float` on line 19. I think I understand that error, but if I change the instantiation of the template on line 39 from `float`s to `string`s (so `vector<string> scales = line_to_vector<string>("0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0")`), the code compiles and runs correctly. Why does this version not generate a compiler error on line 17, since the `string` instantiation would compile that line to assign a `float` to a `string`?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
vector< T > line_to_vector(string line, string sep=" ")
{
    vector< T > input_set;
    size_t pos = line.find(sep);
    T buf;
    while( pos != string::npos )
    {
        if(is_same<T, float>::value)
            buf = stof(line.substr(0, pos));
        else if(is_same<T, string>::value)
            buf = line.substr(0, pos);
        else
        {
            cerr << "Can't process line of type " << typeid(T).name()
                 << ". Please choose float or string." << endl;
            return input_set;
        }

        input_set.push_back(buf);
        if( line.length() )
        {
            pos = line.find(sep);
            line = line.substr(pos+1);
        }
    }
    return input_set;
}

int main()
{
    vector<float> scales = line_to_vector<float>("0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0");
    for(size_t i=0; i<scales.size(); i++)
        cout << scales[i] << ", ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
prompt > g++ comp_err.cc
comp_err.cc:19:19: error: assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'
            buf = line.substr(0, pos);
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
comp_err.cc:39:28: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'line_to_vector<float>' requested here
    vector<float> scales = line_to_vector<float>("0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0");
                           ^
1 error generated.
```

I can avoid this problem entirely if I just drop the templating (this is a simple-enough situation to not really require it), but I want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253286/using-stdis-same-why-my-function-still-cant-work-for-2-types. My question is why the `string` version compiles; I understand why the `float` version does not.

Comment: It would help to reword your question and title to make it more clear the question you are actually asking. When I read it, it sounds like you're asking why the float version does not compile, not why the string version does.

Comment: Float can be assigned to string because that's how string was designed  (not a great design decision but hey)

Comment: I'm not going to post again, though, because using `constexpr` fixes the problem I was having.

Comment: @M.M I don't think that's true; `string s = 4.5;` generates a compiler error

Comment: @mbuuck that is initialization, not assignment. They are different operations despite sharing a common character of syntax

Comment: @M.M ah ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are asking in a roundabout way why there is no error for assigning a float to a string, e.g.:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    x = 5.5f;
}
```

The answer is that this invokes the assignment operator overload ([#4 here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)):

```
basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );
```

There is implicit conversion from `float` to `char`, and the behaviour is to set the string to contain just that character.

This is not a great design decision in hindsight, but `std::string` was designed more than 20 years ago at a time when the language evolution of today had not been foreseen.

Comment: As one of the designers of the original `std::string` (it's been stomped on in many ways since then, but not in a way that affects this) I'd make the same choice today. Yes, C++ has implicit conversions between numeric types. Get used to it! <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker Heh.  Maybe we could do without this particular `operator=` overload?