# How to compile programm with error "no matching function for call to 'to_string'"? c++

Tags: c++

If I have here DATA_T = std::string, I can't compile this code, because of error "no matching function for call to 'to_string'". The function does not allow converting a string to a string. But I need to get the string anyway, how can I work around this error and compile the program?

```
template <typename DATA_T>
std::string get_string(DATA_T subdata) {
  std::string data = "...";
  if (typeid(subdata) == typeid(std::string))
    data += subdata;
  else
    data += std::to_string(subdata);
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Did you turn on C++11 mode or higher in your compiler?

Comment: @NathanOliver OP wants to use this function when `DATA_T` == `std::string`

Comment: Std::to_string does not have an overload that takes std::string as a parameter? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: @DS_London , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253286/using-stdis-same-why-my-function-still-cant-work-for-2-types

Comment: Help. I tripped over "converting a string to a string" and I can't get up

Comment: @DS_London , there isn't the overload to_string, compiler can't function with this value type

Comment: @TimRandall sorry, it's my english, I think. Where isn't to_string(std::string)

Comment: @THND you're okay. The apparent contradiction there is actually the root of your problem. I didn't appreciate that on first reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in other answers you can add a special case for `std::string`. This will solve your problem with `std::string`, but how about other types?

When I first saw `to_string` I was rather disappointed, because it has only a finite set of overloads. However, I misunderstood what `to_string` is meant for. It is meant to convert to string exactly as `std::sprintf` would do with the right format specifier. As `sprintf` is inherited from C, it cannot convert all types to string that you can convert to string in C++. There is no way to enable conversion of custom types via `sprintf` directly. And because of that, `to_string` has the same limitations. In particular there is no `to_string(const std::string&)`.

Overloading `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const T&)` is more flexible. You want to call `get_string` with a `foo` or a `bar`? Why not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename DATA_T>
std::string get_string(DATA_T subdata) {
    std::stringstream data;
    data << "...";
    data << subdata;
    return data.str();
}

struct foo {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const foo& f){
    return out << "foo";
}

int main() {
    foo f;
    std::cout << get_string(f);
}
```

If you actually do want to convert like `sprintf` does, I'd probably stay with one of the solutions presented in the other answers.

Comment: I think you were right to be disappointed in `std::to_string` (I did the original design). Imitating `sprintf` was not a design goal; it was a convenience for the specification. The design goal was to provide a set of easy conversions, and the standard numeric types are an obvious set. The absence of other types, in hindsight, was a failure of imagination. Not to mention fear of complexity. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker then I am glad that I didnt express my dissapointed as harsh as in previous answers ;). In hindsight it is always easy to critize. There is still ADL as customization point. Though I try to avoid ADL, because I consider it too obscure (considering that I also would have to convince coworkers). Overloading `operator<<` is also not free of pitfalls as this answer might suggest. Would it be possible to extend `to_string` in future? I remember a proposal that suggested some `to_string` based on `<<` but iirc it wasnt compatible with current `to_string`.

Comment: I'm not involved in standardization any more, so I don't know what futures may be possible.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of trying to branch on the type of a template argument inside the body of your function, you can write an overload that will be preferred when the argument is a `std::string`.

```
template <typename DATA_T>
std::string get_string(DATA_T subdata) {
  std::string data = "...";
  data += std::to_string(subdata);
  return data;
}

std::string get_string(std::string subdata)
{
  std::string data = "...";
  data += subdata;
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Don't specialize, overload instead.  If you remove `template <>` the code still compiles.  specializations can lead to some confusing hard to find "bugs"

Comment: Good suggestion. Overloading will also mean that types that implicitly convert to `std::string` will be able to use the alternate version. Editing.

Comment: Those will actually still get picked up by the template, as it is a better match.

Comment: Oh, right. I suppose you could SFINAE the template version to only pick up arithmetic types or something, depending on what exactly the valid types for `DATA_T` actually are.

Answer (score 11):

With C++17 it can be made simpler using [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename DATA_T>
std::string get_string(DATA_T subdata) {
  std::string data = "...";
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<DATA_T, std::string>)
    data += subdata;
  else
    data += std::to_string(subdata);
  return data;
}
```

See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672658/7976805) for a pre-C++17 solution.