# How to add a parameter value when forwarding parameters to a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, perfect-forwarding, function-templates

Suppose that I have two functions below, in the `Foo()` function, how can I pack the `hw` string into args and forward them to `Bar()`?

I tried `std::bind` but that didn't work.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void Bar(Args&&... args) 
{
    // do something with args
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void Foo(Args&&... args)
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(std::string)) {
        std::string hw = "Hello, world!";
        Bar<T>(std::forward<Args>(hw, args)...);  // how to add hw to the forward list?
    }
    else {
        Bar<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**: Finally I found my bug! For those of you who's wondering why `hw` doesn't get forwarded to `Bar()` even if you did it right, please pay attention to the `Bar()` in the `else` branch. If `Bar()` expects different types of arguments depending on `T` and the code won't compile, the compiler errors might be emitted by the `else` branch. As @JeJo mentioned, I should have used `if constexpr` instead.

You may find this post helpful:
[using std::is_same, why my function still can't work for 2 types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50253286/using-stdis-same-why-my-function-still-cant-work-for-2-types)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How to add `hw` to the forward list?

Simply

```
Bar<T>(hw, std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or if you want to move the `hw` to `Bar()`

```
#include <utility>      // std::move, std::forward

Bar<T>(std::move(hw), std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or let the compiler deduce the type `T`

```
Bar(std::move(hw), std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

for that, the `Bar` does not required the first template argument `T`

```
template<typename... Args>
void Bar(Args&&... args) 
{
    // ....
}
```

That being said, you might want to change the normal if statement with [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) for compile time branching, as follows:

```
#include <utility>      // std::move, std::forward
#include <type_traits>  // std::is_same_v

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void Foo(Args&&... args) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
    {
        std::string hw = "Hello, world!";
        Bar(std::move(hw), std::forward<Args>(args)...);  
    }
    else
    {
        Bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

Here is the **[complete demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hGxqvfWY4)**

Comment: Maybe OP wanted to move `hw`? Since they are trying to add it to `std::forward`.

Comment: @neo-mashiro By ``Bar(std::move(hw), std::forward<Args>(args)...);``  you receive the argus to `Bar()`  by forwarding reference. You can further forward to any other function from here. By the way you can also `Bar(std::forward<T>(hw), std::forward<Args>(args)...);`

Comment: @Const Yes you're right, but when I tried to change `hw` to a pointer to another object, the code won't compile then, looks like the pointer completely got lost midway, it's not being forwarded as expected, any idea?

Comment: @neo-mashiro You do not need to forward a pointer(not the smart pointer), just let it copy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't realize that `if constexpr` is my real issue until you mentioned it. After changing `if` to `if constexpr`, the code compiles successfully. I was wondering why `Bar()` in the `if` statement doesn't compile even if I passed `hw`, but in fact the one who's actually complaining is the `Bar()` in the `else` branch...... A nasty bug for me to track down!

Comment: @neo-mashiro Glad that it helped ;9

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass hw as std::move(hw) separately to Bar function.